# Python - Resolving PEP8 errors

Tags: python, github, pep8

I'm trying to resolve PEP8 errors that were generated by a Travis build after a pull request to the Firefox UI GitHub repo.  I've been able to reproduce these errors locally using the `pep8` library.  Specifically I have the following line in a file which exceeds the 99 character limit:

```
Wait(self.marionette).until(lambda _: self.autocomplete_results.is_open and len(self.autocomplete_results.visible_results) > 1))
```

The error it produces on running it through `pep8` is given by:

```
$ pep8 --max-line-length=99 --exclude=client firefox_ui_tests/functional/locationbar/test_access_locationbar.py
firefox_ui_tests/functional/locationbar/test_access_locationbar.py:51:100: E501 line too long (136 > 99 characters)
```

The line calls the `Wait().until()` method from the Marionette Python client.  Previously this line was actually two separate lines:

```
Wait(self.marionette).until(lambda _: self.autocomplete_results.is_open)
Wait(self.marionette).until(lambda _: len(self.autocomplete_results.visible_results) > 1)
```

The repo manager advised me to combine these two lines into one, but this has extended the length of the resulting line, causing the PEP8 error.

I could change it back to the way  it was, but is there any way of formatting or indenting the line so that it does not cause this PEP8 error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes;

```
Wait(self.marionette).until(
    lambda _: (
        self.autocomplete_results.is_open and
        len(self.autocomplete_results.visible_results) > 1
    )
)
```

**Check:**

```
$ pep8 --max-line-length=99 --exclude=client foo.py
```

> parens to the rescue! :)